# Trying to add data to my List<book> but getting "No overload for method takes 2 arguements". What can I do?

Tags: c#, console-application

I am making a bookshelf application and I am having an issue trying to add data to my list. Here is the code that I am having trouble with:

```
static List<Book> book = new List<Book>();
public void AddBook()
{
    int bookQuantity;

    string bookTitle, bookAuthor;

    bookQuantity = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    for(int x = 0; x <= bookQuantity; x++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter Title.");
        bookTitle = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Enter Author.");
        bookAuthor = Console.ReadLine();

        Library.Add(bookTitle, bookAuthor);
    }
}
```

When running, I get an error "No overload for method 'Add' takes 2 arguements." Any help/advice is welcome. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need to add **instance of** `Book` in your list, like `Library.Add(new Book {BookTitle = bookTitle, BookAuthor = bookAuthor});`

Comment: What is `Library`? Is it the same as `book`? What does your `Book` class look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change:

```
Library.Add(bookTitle, bookAuthor);
```

to

```
book.Add(new Book() { Title = bookTitle, Author = bookAuthor} );
```

or

```
book.Add(new Book(bookTitle, bookAuthor ); //If you have a relevant constructor
```

Comment: Thank you. Sorry for my question being rather vague or not quite up to standard, I am quite new to all of this.

Answer (score 1):

Create an instance of Book inside the loop

```
for(int x = 0; x <= bookQuantity; x++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter Title.");
    bookTitle = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Enter Author.");
    bookAuthor = Console.ReadLine();
    Book bookObj = new Book();
    bookObj.bookTitle = bookTitle ;
    bookObj.bookAuthor = bookAuthor ;
    Library.Add(bookObj);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to add a `Book` to your `List<Book>`... but you're not actually *creating* a `Book` instance. You probably want:

```
Book book = new Book(bookTitle, bookAuthor);
books.Add(book);
```

... that's after you've changed the name of your `List<Book>` variable to `books`, too. It should almost certainly be an instance variable, too. Additionally, I'd stop declaring variables at the start of your method - declare them where you need them. For example:

```
private readonly List<Book> books = new List<Book>();

public void AddBooks()
{
    Console.WriteLine("How many books would you like to add?");
    int count = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    // Note change from <= to <
    for(int x = 0; x < count; x++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter Title.");
        string title = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Enter Author.");
        string author = Console.ReadLine();

        books.Add(new Book(title, author));
    }
}
```

You might *also* want to separate the "asking how many books to add" from the "adding a book" part:

```
private readonly List<Book> books = new List<Book>();

public void AddMultipleBooks()
{
    Console.WriteLine("How many books would you like to add?");
    int count = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    for(int x = 0; x < count; x++)
    {
        AddBook();
    }
 }

 public void AddBook()
 {
    Console.WriteLine("Enter Title.");
    string title = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine("Enter Author.");
    string author = Console.ReadLine();

    books.Add(new Book(title, author));
}
```

Then consider whether the user input should really be in *this* class, or possibly a class which *calls* this one. (Think about how difficult it is to unit test this code, for example.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
book.Add(new Book(bookTitle, bookAuthor));
```

Of course you should have class Book, something like this:

```
public class Book
{
   public Book (String title, String author)
   {
      Title = title;
      Author = author;
   }

   public String Title { get; private set; }
   public String Author { get; private set; }
}
```